# About Lie algebra cohomology and Ext group

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over a field $K$. Then the Lie algebra cohomology of $\mathfrak{g}$ with coefficients in $V$ is the right derived
functor of $V\mapsto V^\mathfrak{g}$ and can be described by Ext functor: $H^*(\mathfrak{g},V) \cong \mathrm{Ext}^*_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(K, V)$.

**My question:** I know that $H^*(\mathfrak{g},V)=\bigoplus_{i}H^i(\mathfrak{g},V)$. What is about $\mathrm{Ext}^*_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(K, V)$? Does $\mathrm{Ext}^*_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(K, V)=\bigoplus_{i}\mathrm{Ext}^i_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(K, V)$?

Comment: Isn't this true just by definition?

Comment: I think you are right. Sorry for asking stupid question. I just want to make sure that is true.